# MQTT Message to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, mqtt

I want to transform a MQTT message I recieved in JSON format (for example: {"event":"value","type":"r","value":0} ) to a JSONObject and I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried this:

```java
public void messageArrived(String t, MqttMessage m) throws Exception {
            String message = m.toString();
            JSONObject jsonmsg = (JSONObject) JSONObject.stringToValue(message); 
}
```

But that is not really working. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Which MQTT implementation and JSON parsing library are you using? I think your mistake is using `MqttMessage.toString()` which is probably intended for human readability rather than a way to retrieve the message for further processing.

Comment: Im getting them both via Maven. For MQTT: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
and for JSON:  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should retrieve the message's payload with the `getPayload()` method, which returns a `byte[]` since MQTT isn't a text-only protocol.

You can then make a `String` out of that `byte[]` and a `JSONObject` out of that `String` as follows :

```
JSONObject jsonmsg = new JSONObject(new String(m.getPayload());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it